# Find a prefix based on trie search | | python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem :
Given a list of business_names (strings) and a searchTerm (string).
Return a list of business_names that contains searchTerm as prefix in the business_names.

```
Example 1.
Input:

business_names[] = { "burger king", "McDonald's", "super duper burger's", "subway", "pizza hut"}
searchTerm = "bur"

Ouput:
["burger king", "super duper burger's"]
```

I have tried solving in this below way.

But I want to implement trie approach to solve this problem. some one please help here?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

Any linear solution to solve

```
def prefix(business_names, searchTerm):
    split = [i.split() for i in business_names]
    ans = []
    for name in split:
        for i in range(len(name)):
            query = ' '.join(name[i:])
            if query.startswith(searchTerm):
                ans.append(name)
                break
    return [' '.join(i) for i in ans]
```

Comment: There are some problems in your sample input and code: `business_name[]`? and never use `split` as variable name - since it's a built-in name. Use something else like `parts` is better.

Comment: Can you please also explain what do you mean by `trie`?  The Data Structure?

Comment: why do you use so many `for`-loops ? you could `split()` in second loop instead of creating list `split`. And then you could use originla name directly in append() and later you would no need to use `" ".join()`

Comment: It's not really clear why `bur` is considered a prefix in `super duper burger's`. It you want to use a trie with this definition of prefix, you will need a trie of individual words, then a structure that maps words to business names.

Comment: @furas could you help me here?

Comment: @MarkMeyer could you please help me with this approach here

Comment: it seems nobody know what means `trie approach` and you have to explain it. In question (not in comment) you could add description or link to some explanation - maybe on Wikipedia.

Comment: it seems in your link you have some implementation in Python - and as you see it is complex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what means `trie approach` and if this is what you need but I would write it simpler - without `join`, `range`, `len`

To make sure I use also `lower()`

```
business_names = ["burger king", "McDonald's", "super duper burger's", "subway", "pizza hut"]
searchTerm = "bur"


def prefix(business_names, searchTerm):
    searchTerm = searchTerm.lower()

    results  = []
    for name in business_names:
        for word in name.split(' '):
            word = word.lower()
            if word.startswith(searchTerm):
                results.append(name)
                break

    return results
    
print(prefix(business_names, searchTerm))
```

---

**EDIT:**

I took code from link and create this code.

But I had to change two things.

- it works only with letters `a-z` so I have to remove `'` and convert to `lower()`
- it search only full words but after removing `and pCrawl.isEndOfWord` in `return pCrawl != None and pCrawl.isEndOfWord` it seems it find words which stats with `searchTerm`

But I have one doubt: maybe it can search better then `O(n^2)` but first it has to build `Trie` and it also need some time. So it can be useful when you always search in the same text and you have to build `Trie` only once. But you have to build separated `Trie` for every business name - and it doesn't have to be faster.

.

```
class TrieNode: 
      
    # Trie node class 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.children = [None]*26
  
        # isEndOfWord is True if node represent the end of the word 
        self.isEndOfWord = False
  
class Trie: 
      
    # Trie data structure class 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = self.getNode() 
  
    def getNode(self): 
      
        # Returns new trie node (initialized to NULLs) 
        return TrieNode() 
  
    def _charToIndex(self,ch): 
          
        # private helper function 
        # Converts key current character into index 
        # use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case 
          
        return ord(ch)-ord('a') 
  
  
    def insert(self, key): 
          
        # If not present, inserts key into trie 
        # If the key is prefix of trie node,  
        # just marks leaf node 
        pCrawl = self.root 
        length = len(key) 
        for level in range(length): 
            index = self._charToIndex(key[level]) 
  
            # if current character is not present 
            if not pCrawl.children[index]: 
                pCrawl.children[index] = self.getNode() 
            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index] 
  
        # mark last node as leaf 
        pCrawl.isEndOfWord = True
  
    def search(self, key): 
          
        # Search key in the trie 
        # Returns true if key presents  
        # in trie, else false 
        pCrawl = self.root 
        length = len(key) 
        for level in range(length): 
            index = self._charToIndex(key[level]) 
            if not pCrawl.children[index]: 
                return False
            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index] 
  
        return pCrawl != None #and pCrawl.isEndOfWord  # <-- check `isEndOfWord` to search full words
  
# driver function 

def prefix(business_names, searchTerm):
  
    searchTerm = searchTerm.lower()

    results  = []
    
    for name in business_names:
    
        # Input keys (use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case) 
        # remove `'`  and convert to list with lower case words
        keys = name.lower().replace("'", "").split(" ")
        #print('keys:', keys)
        
        # Trie object 
        t = Trie() 
  
        # Construct trie 
        for key in keys: 
            #print('key:', key)
            t.insert(key) 

        # Search in trie
        if t.search(searchTerm) is True:
            results.append(name)        
        
    return results
  
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    business_names = ["burger king", "McDonald's", "super duper burger's", "subway", "pizza hut"]
    searchTerm = "bur"
    
    results = prefix(business_names, searchTerm)

    print( results )
```

Comment: Thanks @furas for optimising  my code, I still need trie approach to this problem. As the above code is O(n^2).

Comment: then you have to explain what is `trie approach` because it seems nobody know what this means. You could add description in question or link to some explanation - maybe on Wikipedia.

Comment: I mean this approach. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/ @furas

Comment: it seems in this link you already have some implementation in Python.

Comment: yes , but I am struggling with how to actually implement here in this case.

Comment: I tried to use original code from link to search it but I found two problems -(1) it works only with letters so char `'` makes problem. (2) it search only full words, not words which starts with term. All this means it may need a lot chages. Other problem I see - maybe it can search better then `O(n^2)` but first it has to build `Trie` and it also need some time - so it can be useful when you always search in the same text and you have to build `Trie` only once. But you have to build separated Trie for every business name.

Comment: I added code which uses code from your link